# Jobs still targets my current location, even though I unticked the preference

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I've filed a profile on SO Jobs, where I say that I live in Paris. I'm moving to Dublin, so in the match preferences, I say that I am looking for Jobs in Dublin and I unchecked the "Always include your current location" as well as the "Willing to work remotely" checkboxes.

However I keep receiving mails proposing Paris jobs instead of Dublin jobs. This is a bug, right?

Comment: Do you have any Job Alerts that you need to clear as well? https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts

Comment: No, I don't have any (but I didn't know about this page though, thanks)